# How to integrate rewarded video ad in android using admob?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, rewardedvideoad

I want to add rewarded video ad in my android project using admob , i monetized my android app with rewarded video. I followed this link [integrate rewarded video ad](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/rewarded-video)

Here is mainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
private RewardedVideoAd mAd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);

}

private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
 mAd.loadAd(String.valueOf(R.string.ad_key), new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("device id").build());
    Toast.makeText(this, "called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
public void load(View view){
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}


@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    if (mAd.isLoaded()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "is Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mAd.show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + reward.getType() + "  amount: " +
            reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    mAd.resume(this);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mAd.pause(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mAd.destroy(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Here is my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

when i run my code it shows

> 02-28 18:30:19.573 21418-21429/mainscreen.udeveloper.com.rewardedvideo W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
>
> 02-28 18:30:19.583 21418-21418/mainscreen.udeveloper.com.rewardedvideo W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 1

I search lot on google for rewarded video ad tutorial but i did not found any tutorial please help me.
If i should use another rewarded video ad network please guide me good tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

```
Use this Id for Testing : - ca-app-pub-4824494878097656/8403117409

package com.safal.bhatia;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener;

public class Demo extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {

    private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
rewardAds();
    }
    private void rewardAds() {
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }

    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-4824494878097656/8403117409",//use this id for testing
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Download to Earn" + reward.getType() + "  amount: " +
                reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Reward the user.
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
            mRewardedVideoAd.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`enter code here`
    }

}
```

Comment: Use this Id for Testing : - ca-app-pub-4824494878097656/8403117409